# Sub-setting data in R

Tags: r

[image]

I need to subset my data in R to only include the following Isolates: Isolate 10, Isolate 11 and Isolate 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dplyr::filter(your_data_frame, Isolate %in% paste("Isolate", 10:12))
```

Instead of using paste you could also list the names in a vector using `c()`, but this way you only need to type "Isolate" once.

Comment: so it would be                                                                                
        dplyr::filter(your_data_frame, Isolate %in% paste(c("Isolate 10", "Isolate 11", 
        "Isolate12"))     ??

Comment: this will work with an additional closing parentheses at the end, yes, but the paste isn't doing anything there, so you should omit it: dplyr::filter(your_data_frame, Isolate %in% c("Isolate 10", "Isolate 11", "Isolate12"))